# Does Erza die in episode 10, 2014?

Tags: fairy-tail

### Massive, massive spoilers. Do not read the answers that may pop up!!!!

In Fairy Tail (2014), Episode 10, Kagura unsheathes her sword and it apparently looks like she  killed Erza. I have not been reading the manga lately and haven't read the latest chapter of fairy tail.

So does Erza die?

Screenshots:

[image]
[image]

If you didn't understand from the screenshots, Kagura finds out that Simon died because of Erza's weakness. Kagura draws her sword, Erza says "sorry", and we hear her slash her sword and see the next scene where there is blood.

Comment: no, she still alive

Comment: @ShinobuOshino- I had a feeling someone would say this. xD

Comment: No main charters die in Fairy Tail...

Comment: The preview does show her alive and kicking...

Comment: She died and reborn as Kushina Uzumaki  :v

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, she still alive, it's Erza after all

I'll try to keep the spoiler to minimum so if you really want to now what happen next you can read it on your own, or wait for next episode, this is a next chapter from manga after that episode

**Chapter 315: Rosemary**

> [image: Chapter 315]

Comment: Thanks for that. I can't wait till the next episode. (Woo-hoo).

Answer (score 0):

Without spoilers -
As a fairy tail mage, she will make sure hatred will never win and Kagura will come to her senses on the matter of Jellal.

Answer (score 0):

After watching **Fairy Tail (2014), Episode 11**.

> Erza does not die, neither does she get hit. In the animation, **the blood is not supposed to be there**. In the comic, Erza was hit in the right shoulder by Kagura's slash, while in the animation they edited this part out.
>  
>  [image: enter image description here !]
>  [image: enter image description here !]